# Swift: Is there a way to make sure only a particular class can create an object of an other class

Tags: swift, oop, factory-method

We have 2 classes BaseClassA and ClassB. BaseClassA have multiple subclasses like the following

SubClassA1.swift

```
class SubClassA1 : BaseClassA {
    private var someFlag = false
    private var context: SomeContextClass?

    func setContext(_ context: SomeContextClass) {

    }
}
```

ClassB.swift

```
class ClassB {
    func create() -> BaseClassA {
        //This method will create object of SubClassA1 and return
    }
}
```

We would like the outside world to always use ClassB to create objects of SubClassA1 and not directly create objects of SubClassA1. Is there a way to make sure that only ClassB can instantiate objects of SubClassA1?

Answer (score 0):

In the SubClassA1 init method, call

```
Thread.callStackSymbols
```

It returns an array of strings with details of the thread's stack. Second string in the array will give you the details of the class and method that invoked the init method. So you can generates an assertion if a its not called from SubClassB1.

Comment: Apart it is much easier to use `#file` or `#function` literals, does the `Thread.callStackSymbols` return a real name, but not just an address running in non-debug environment? Also, how slow is it?

Comment: I agree. #function literal is better than Thread.callStackSymbols. However this mean we assume the class/sub-classes would be named with a particular convention for it to work correctly in all the cases.